# How to find an object in a vector, that has certain value in 'variable_name'(variable can be several objects away inside)?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, I have a vector of objects `D`, I would like to get all `D` objects, that have `interestingIntVariable1` between 10 and 20(variables can be int/float). How best can I do it? In the end I will have an UI where user will set range of values for one or more variables, and should get a smaller vector of D objects as a result.

Right now I'm thinking about implementing getters for each variable, but most often each variable will need several layers of getters.. and I have around **280** such variables in each `D` object. Or I can make all variables public and have one getter for each.. is it okay solution?

```
struct A{
    int interestingIntVariable1;
};
struct B1 : public A{
    int interestingIntVariable2;
    int objectType;
};
struct B2 : public A{
    int interestingIntVariable2;
    int objectType;
};
struct C{
    int interestingIntVariable3;
    std::vector<A*> bObjects;
};
struct D{
    int interestingIntVariable4;
    //severalObjectsLikeC here
    C objectC;
    ...
};

std::vector<D> dObjects;
```

Will be nice to have something similar to css selectors
so that I could make searches like this:

```
((D > C > bObjects > objectType) == 'B1', 0 < (D > C > bObjects > interestingIntVariable1) < 10 )
```

Edit:
more like this:

```
((dObjects > objectC > bObjects > objectType) == 'B1', 0 < (dObjects > objectC > bObjects > interestingIntVariable1) < 10 )
```

Another example:

I have a Car class. Each Car has an Engine object and manufacture date. Each Engine has Cylinders array. Each cylinder has its id inside an engine and damaged property between 0.0 and 1.0.

I want to find all cars, that have been produced before 1999 and cylinder with id=2 has damaged < 0.4. I used 3 variables here. I have 280 such variables.

Edit2:
Can I at least gather all 'relative' pointers to all these variables into the map during their initialization?

Comment: 280 variables in a single class? You do have a design issue.

Comment: @Torbjörn not in a single. In total inside D class. For example D class has some variables + 7 C-like objects. Each C-like object has several variables and an array of different B-like objects, each of them has some variables.

Comment: What about `std::copy_if`? Something like this: `copy_if(dObjects.begin(), dObjects.end(), std::back_inserter(dObjects2), [](D i) { return i.interestingIntVariable1 > 10 && i.interestingIntVariable1 < 20; });`

Comment: maybe pointers to member would be useful somehow?

Comment: @slawekwin I was thinking that maybe there is a more elegant way.. I will see into it right now, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried storing your objects in a database and using sql? It looks like you want to implement half a sql engine.

Comment: @adrianN I think it's too complex for my purposes, plus a lot of these variables will be changing >50 times per second.

Comment: @userqwerty1 [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) is certainly capable of updating things quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a custom predicate function (i.e. lambda) you can tune the behavior of most std-algorithms.

As @DimChtz suggested in a comment, `std::copy_if` is a good start with the custom predicate function returning true if (and only if) at least one `A`-derived object in `bObjects` has `interstingIntVariable` between 10 and 20.

```
std::vector<D> matched;
std::copy_if(dObjects.cbegin(), dObject.cend(), std::back_inserter(matched),
  [](auto dObj) {
    return std::find_if(dObj.objectC.bObjects.cbegin(),
                        dObj.objectC.bObjects.cend(),
                        [](auto aObj) {
                          return aObj->interestingIntVariable1 > 10 && aObj->interestingIntVariable1 < 20;
                        }) != bObjects.cend();
  });
```

The inner `std::find_if` will return an iterator to the first `A*` in `bObjects` if the predicate returns true, else it returns the *past-the-end* iterator.

You can adjust the inner predicate to filter out those `A*` objects which do not match a certain `objectType` value.